# Automapper map from dataset columns to list of object

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I've a dataset with 3 fixed columns and other variables, the dataset is created in C # through a stored procedure.

[image]

I want to map the dataset with this object via Automapper:

```
public class PrivacyStatusData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public List<ConsentData> ConsentList { get; set; }
}

public class ConsentData
{
    public string ConsentName { get; set; } // Consent1 Column Name
    public bool ConsentValue { get; set; } // Consent1 Value
    public DateTime ConsentDate { get; set; } // Consent1Date Value
}
```

Tanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on my own. Static properties are mapped through the MapFrom function and dynamic properties are mapped through a custom resolver. The trick is to map a DataRow instead of a DataTable.

The CreateMap definition:

```
    CreateMap<DataRow, PrivacyStatusData>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, orig => orig.MapFrom(row => (int)row["Id"]))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, orig => orig.MapFrom(row => row["Name"].ToString()))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Surname, orig => orig.MapFrom(row => row["Surname"].ToString()))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ConsentList, orig => orig.MapFrom<DataRowToConsentDataResolver>());
```

The resolver:

```
public class DataRowToConsentDataResolver : IValueResolver<DataRow, PrivacyStatusData, List<ConsentData>>
{
    public List<ConsentData> Resolve(DataRow source, PrivacyStatusData destination, List<ConsentData> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var consentDataList = new List<ConsentData>();

        for (int i = 9; i < source.Table.Columns.Count; i += 2)
        {
            var consentData = new ConsentData();
            var consentName = source.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName.Replace("Consenso", "");
            consentName = consentName.First().ToString().ToUpper() + consentName.Substring(1).ToLower();
            consentData.ConsentName = consentName;

            if (source[i].ToString() == "1")
                consentData.ConsentValue = true;

            consentData.ConsentDate = "-";
            var dtDate = new DateTime();
            if (DateTime.TryParse(source[i + 1].ToString(), out dtDate))
                consentData.ConsentDate = dtDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");

            consentDataList.Add(consentData);
        }

        return consentDataList;
    }
}
```

Tha caller:

```
   private List<PrivacyStatusData> MapDataTableToPrivacyStatusData(DataTable privacyData)
   {
        var rows = new List<DataRow>(privacyData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>());
        var privacyStatusDataList = mapper.Map<List<DataRow>, List<PrivacyStatusData>>(rows);

        return privacyStatusDataList;
   }
```

Comment: This is manual mapping. I don't see how AM is helping you here.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I know, but I have automapper in the project, so it makes sense to use a centralized system instead of different types of mapping. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Search the AM repo, there should be smth there.

Comment: Other than that, clearly a type converter is a better way. Manual all the way :)